# Minimal axioms necessary to prove the incompleteness theorems?

Tags: axioms, incompleteness

What's the minimal sufficient (plausibly) consistent system of axioms to prove the First incompleteness theorem? More interestingly can the First incompleteness theorem be proved in a consistent self-verifying theory?

What about the second theorem? Given that this is a stronger result I would expect the axiomatic systems to be different.

EDIT (clarification):
What's the minimal (plausibly) consistent theory needed to prove the First Incompleteness theorem about some theory T, including a sufficient fragment of Robinson arithmetic **Q**,

Comment: See [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) as well as Beeson's [Lecture 14 : Robinson’s Arithmetic and Church’s theorem](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/presentation/a2e8/dc0bade593559863315e8a033f81bde984bb.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean with "a self-verifying theory" ?

Comment: a more interesting question is the minimal axioms for the second incompleteness theorem.

Comment: I mean self-verifying theory as a theory to which incompleteness theorems don't apply, i.e. can prove its own consistency.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus indeed that's an interesting question, but I am interested in the first as afaik it's a weaker result, hmm thinking about it I am interested in results on both.

Comment: If a "self-verifying theory" is "a theory $T$ to which incompleteness theorems don't apply", with "can the First incompleteness theorem be proved **in it**" do you mean : use theory $T$ to prove the Inc.Th about some different theory $T'$ ?

Comment: yes, from T proving the incompleteness of T'

Comment: I would expect T' to be some fragment ***Q***.

Comment: An inconsistent theory is self-verifying because it can correctly prove its own completeness.  The minimal set is then the axiom $A \wedge \lnot A$.  This sounds flip, but is a challenge to the formulation of the question.  You need a theory that can prove its consistency as well as its completeness to satisfy the spirit of the question.

Comment: If I read your edit correctly you are asking about strength of the meta theory needed to prove GIT, not of the object theory that GIT applies to. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118183/what-axioms-are-used-to-prove-godels-incompleteness-theorems